# Get last and most values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table user_places like this:

```
user_id  recorded_date  place_visited
2        2016-04-05     NY
2        2016-04-07     UK
2        2016-04-08     UK
2        2016-04-08     UK
3        2016-04-08     AUS
3        2016-04-09     AUS
2        2016-04-15     NY
3        2016-04-15     CAN
```

I am trying to get the place visited in last recorded_date of user and name of the place that he has visited the most.

i.e

```
user_id  recorded_date_last  place_visited_most last_visited_place
    2        2016-04-15       UK                    NY
    3        2016-04-15       AUS                  CAN
```

Comment: `user_id = 2` doesn't have a date `2016-04-15` associated with him. How come this date appears in the result set?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using a subquery:

```
select * ,  
    (select place_visited from mytable t2
    where t2.user_id = t1.user_id
    group by place_visited
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1) place_visited_most
from mytable t1
where recorded_date = (select max(recorded_date) from mytable)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad351/4

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested stab at it. I'm not as familiar with MySQL so there may be other approaches that work better. This is a set-based method that avoids using `limit` and `order by`.

```
select t.user_id, t.place_visited, modex.cnt, maxd.max_recorded_date
from
    T t inner join
    (
        select user_id, max(recorded_date) as max_recorded_date from T
        group by user_id
    ) maxd
        on maxd.user_id = t.user_id
    inner join
    (
        select user_id, max(cnt) as max_cnt
        from
        (
            select user_id, count(*) as cnt from T
            group by user_id, place_visited
        ) counts
        group by user_id
    ) maxc
        on maxc.user_id = t.user_id
    inner join
    (
        select user_id, cnt, min(place_visited) as place_most_visited
        from
        (
            select user_id, place_visited, count(*) as cnt from T
            group by user_id, place_visited
        ) break_ties
        group by user_id, cnt
    ) modex
        on      modex.user_id = maxd.user_id
            and maxc.max_cnt = modex.cnt and modex.place_most_visited = t.place_visited
```

Since you could have ties for the mode of `place_visited` I just kept the lowest alphabetically. I did assume that there would be no ties for `recorded_date` though.